# Looping through nc files in R

Tags: r, loops, ncdf4

Good morning everyone,
I am currently using the code written by Antonio Olinto Avila-da-Silva on this link: https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/forum/oceancolor/topic_show.pl?tid=5954
It allows me to extract data of type sst/chlor_a from nc file. It uses a loop to create an excel file with all the data. Unfortunately, I noticed that the function only takes the first data file in the loop. Thus, I find myself with 20 times the same data in a row in my excel file.
Does anyone have a solution to make this loop work properly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It'll be easier for people to assist if the question is reproducible. Here's a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with tips and tricks. Since SO will live on forever, it's important to make questions as self-contained as possible. The URL above could go away on a moment's notice and leave this question orphaned...having said that, I skimmed the script and identified what I think the problem is, but can't say with certainty since this isn't reproducible. Answer below. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would first check out that these two lines contain all the files you are expecting:

```
(f <- list.files(".", pattern="*.L3m_MO_SST_sst_9km.nc",full.names=F))
(lf<-length(f))
```

And then there's a bug in the for-loop. This line:

```
data<-nc_open(f)
```

Needs to reference the iterator `i`, so change it to something like this:

```
data<-nc_open(f[[i]])
```

It appears both scripts have this same bug.